# Using Django ORM query How to annotate if multiple levels of foreign key hierarchy exists

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-annotate

My Django models looks like

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(('name'), max_length=30)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    name = models.CharField(('name'), max_length=30)

class GrandChild(models.Model):
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child)
    name = models.CharField(('name'), max_length=30)

-> To Get Number of Childs for parent following query does               
    Parent.objects.annotate(childs=Count('Child')).values('childs')

-> To Get Number of Grand Childs for parent following query does               
    Parent.objects.annotate(childs=Count('child')).annotate(grandchilds=Count('child__grandchild'))
```

But how can I get the count of number of childs and number of grand childs for each parent

Comment: These kinds of things are solved with recursion, for example you make a get_children method that iterates over each child and calls their get_children until there are no more to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `distinct`:

```
Count('child', distinct=True)
```

More details by link:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations